Time-varying Normal copulas, generating residulas with parameters
I am working with time-varying normal copulas who equation is given by

The dynamic equation of dependence parameter $\rho$ is :

Where
$u_1=F_1 (ε_{1,t} )$       and       $u_2=F_2 (ε_{2,t} ) $
I found the values of the parameters as follows:-
My $ω_N=0.0433$ $ β_N=-0.1718$    and    $α_N=0.6016$  and $ρ_0= -0.0699$.
I now need to generate a vector of ($\hat{ε_{1,t}}$ ) ̂  and  ($\hat{ε_{2,t}}$ )  for forecasting and comparing models. How do I generate them in Excel or R.
